# R closure scope

Tags: r, closures

I try to understand closures in R.

Can someone explain me why this code (1):

```
vars <- c("one", "two")
funcs <- list()

for (v in vars) {
  funcs[[length(funcs) + 1]] <- function() {
    print(v)
  }
}

funcs[[1]]()
funcs[[2]]()
```

returns

```
[1] "two"
[1] "two"
```

but following code (2):

```
vars <- c("one", "two")
funcs <- list()

getFunc <- function(v) {
  v_i <- v
  function() {
    print(v_i)
  }
}

for (v in vars) {
  funcs[[length(funcs) + 1]] <- getFunc(v)
}

funcs[[1]]()
funcs[[2]]()
```

returns:

```
[1] "one"
[1] "two"
```

As addition, this code still prints only "two" (3):

```
vars <- c("one", "two")
funcs <- list()

for (v in vars) {
  v_i <- v
  funcs[[length(funcs) + 1]] <- function() {
    print(v_i)
  }
}

funcs[[1]]()
funcs[[2]]()
```

And this also prints only "two" (4):

```
vars <- c("one", "two")
funcs <- list()

getFunc <- function(v) {
  function() {
    print(v)
  }
}

for (v in vars) {
  funcs[[length(funcs) + 1]] <- getFunc(v)
}

funcs[[1]]()
funcs[[2]]()
```

I am guessing that v is reused so it points always to the same space in memory. But can we be sure that v will always be the last value of the list - it would persist in time or it is volatile?

(3) mean that is not enough to assign value to other variable it has to be in separate function.

(4) mean that argument of function is also reused.

Comment: After `for (v in vars)`, check the value of `v` (it is the last value, grabbed by lazy evaluation when the function is called)... If you want to carry a value with a function, maybe try `f = local({v = 2; function(x) x + v})`. I guess most of the answers can be found in `RShowDoc("R-intro", type = "html")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `v` in the global environment only has a single value at any one time but as the `for` loop changes the value of `v` changes.  On the first iteration `v` is `"one"` and on the second iteration it is `"two"` and since `v` is not subsequently changed it stays at the value `"two"`.  Now,

**1)** In the first case when you call `funcs[[1]]()` it looks for `v` in `funcs[[1]]` and can't find it so it looks in the `environment(funcs[[1]])` and that is the global environment.

```
environment(funcs[[1]])
## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

The value of `v` in the global environment at the time that `funcs[[1]]` is run is "two" so it prints that.

**2)** In the second example when you call `funcs[[1]]()` it looks for `v_i` in `funcs[[1]]` and can't find it so again it looks in `environent(funcs[[1]])` but now the environment of `funcs[[1]]` is the runtime environment within `getfunc`. 
 Each time `getfunc` is run that environment will be different.  Anyways within that environment `v_i` has the value `"one"` so it prints that.

```
environment(funcs[[1]])
## <environment: 0x00000000097418d0>
```

**3)** The third example is basically the same situation as the first.  `v_i` is in the global environment and has the value `"two"` at the time `funcs[[1]()` is run.

**4)** In the fourth example the `environment(funcs[[1]])` is the runtime environment within `getfunc`; however, because the `v` argument to `getfunc` has not been accessed prior to `funcs[[1]]` being called, `v` is still an unevaluated promise.  When `funcs[[1]]` is finally called it needs to use `v` the promise is evaluated and at that point `v` is `"two"`.